# Add previous column alias to calculate sum/total of last column

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a query which I need to optimize. It is using 3 subqueries 2 times each. Below is the query.

```
select i.itemid, b.itemname, i.batchno,
        (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
            where itemid = i.itemid
            and batchno = i.batchno
            and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
            and dateinvent < '2018-12-26 00:00:00') as openingBal ,
        (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
            where itemid = i.itemid
            and batchno = i.batchno
            and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
            and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
            and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
            and qty>0
            ) as inputQty,
        (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
            where itemid = i.itemid
            and batchno = i.batchno
            and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
            and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
            and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
            and qty<0
            )as outputQty ,
        (
             COALESCE((select sum(qty) from inventtrans
                where itemid = i.itemid
                and batchno = i.batchno
                and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
                and dateinvent < '2018-12-26 00:00:00'),0)
            +
             COALESCE((select sum(qty) from inventtrans
                where itemid = i.itemid
                and batchno = i.batchno
                and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
                and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
                and qty>0),0)
            +
             COALESCE((select sum(qty) from inventtrans
                where itemid = i.itemid
                and batchno = i.batchno
                and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
                and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
                and qty<0),0)
        ) as bal,
            i.location,
            -- split_part(i.inventsizeid, '/+[0-9]', 2) as size
            i.inventsizeid as size,
            i.configid as color
from inventtrans i, view_inventbatchtrans b
where
i.batchno = b.batchid
group by i.itemid,b.itemname,i.batchno,i.qty,i."location",i.inventsizeid,i.configid;
```

check the query for openingBal, inputQty, outputQt. 
I need to add these 3 columns to get bal column. Here is the query which I optimized.

```
select i.itemid, b.itemname, i.batchno, i.openingBal, i.inputQty, i.outputQty, i.bal, i.location, i.inventsizeid as size, i.configid as color
from (select i.*,
  (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
    where itemid = i.itemid
    and batchno = i.batchno
    and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
    and dateinvent < '2018-12-26 00:00:00') as openingBal,
    (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
        where itemid = i.itemid
        and batchno = i.batchno
        and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
        and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
        and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
        and qty>0
      ) as inputQty,
      (select sum(qty) from inventtrans
          where itemid = i.itemid
          and batchno = i.batchno
          and inventlocationid = 'locationId'
          and dateinvent >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
          and dateinvent <= '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
          and qty<0
        )as outputQty, (COALESCE(i.openingBal, 0) + COALESCE(i.inputQty, 0) + COALESCE(i.outputQty, 0)) as bal
      from inventtrans i
    ) i, view_inventbatchtrans b
        where
        i.batchno = b.batchid
        group by i.itemid,b.itemname,i.batchno,i.qty,i."location",i.inventsizeid,i.configid;`
 Where I run optimized query it throwing an error as
```

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column i.openingbal does not exist
>         Position: 937 which is at `(COALESCE(i.openingBal, 0) + COALESCE(i.inputQty, 0) + COALESCE(i.outputQty, 0)) as bal

Could you tell what is it that I'm doing wrong. Can we use alias column for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are only available in GROUP BY, ORDER BY or HAVING (aside from direct output).
Found this link as helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932205/to-calculate-sum-two-alias-named-columns-in-sql?rq=1

Please check it.